# Using the Dash Upload component to post csv file

Tags: csv, post, python-requests, postman, plotly-dash

I would like to upload a csv file using the Dash Upload Component (see [Example from Dash Documentation](https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/upload)) and post it to a file-server. I want it to work as simple as this [working Postman csv Post-Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KT2xr.png). 
My callback currently looks like this:

```
@app.callback(
Output(component_id="eventlog-dropdown", component_property="options"),
[Input(component_id="upload-data", component_property="contents"),
 Input(component_id="upload-data", component_property="filename")]
)
def upload_eventlog(uploaded_contents, uploaded_filename):
    if uploaded_contents is not None:
        eventlog_data = [
            parse_contents(c, n) for c, n in
            zip(uploaded_contents, uploaded_filename)]

        files = {'file': (uploaded_filename[0], str(eventlog_data))}

        print(files)

        requests.post(MIDDLEWARE_ENDPOINT+"data/upload-eventlog", files=files)

        #Updates the dropdown "eventlog-dropdown"
        files = requests.get(MIDDLEWARE_ENDPOINT + 'data/geteventloglist').json()
        options = [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in files]
        return options
    elif uploaded_contents is None:
        files = requests.get(MIDDLEWARE_ENDPOINT + 'data/geteventloglist').json()
        options = [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in files]
        return options
```

The parse contents function looks like this:

```
def parse_contents(contents, filename):
content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')

decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
try:
    if 'csv' in filename:
        # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV file
        df = pd.read_csv(
            io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
        return df
    elif 'xls' in filename:
        # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
        df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
        return df
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    return html.Div([
        'There was an error processing this file.'
    ])
```

The post 'works'. It posts the csv-file and the csv-file is getting stored on the file-server. However, the csv is not comma-seperated anymore and truncated:

```
69  FN322        Landing  2019-05-22 04:35         Berlin       12:20      4           12.333333
70  FN322  Baggage claim  2019-05-22 03:05         Berlin       01:40      5            1.666667

[71 rows x 7 columns]]
```

Do you guys know any easy way to post the uploaded filename and contents within the Dash Upload component like the way Postman does it? Or how I could at least save all of the file content?

Thank you very much in advance and have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. It was because of the following lines of code:

```
`df = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))`
```

To upload the csv file, we do not want it to be a text stream. It needs to be a byte-like object. The code:

```
decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
```

already returns a bytes-object such that we only need to return that object. So, the parse_contents() function now looks like this:

```
def parse_contents(contents, filename):
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')

    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)

    try:
        if 'csv' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV file
            return decoded
     except Exception as e:
        return html.Div([
        'There was an error processing this file.'
    ])
```

Note that I'm currently only interested in csv-files. That is why I removed the xlsx part. Unfortunately, I do not know whether the code also works for xlsx-files. 
The code

```
eventlog_data = [
        parse_contents(c, n) for c, n in
        zip(uploaded_contents, uploaded_filename)]
```

defines a list with the decoded bytes-object being the first element within that list. So the files-argument of our post-request has to take the first element of out eventlog-data in order to send the byte-data:

```
files = {'file': (uploaded_filename[0], eventlog_data[0])}
```

The final callback looks like this:

```
@app.callback(
Output(component_id="eventlog-dropdown", component_property="options"),
[Input(component_id="upload-data", component_property="contents"),
 Input(component_id="upload-data", component_property="filename")]
)
def upload_eventlog(uploaded_contents, uploaded_filename):
    if uploaded_contents is not None:
        eventlog_data = [
            parse_contents(c, n) for c, n in
            zip(uploaded_contents, uploaded_filename)]
        files = {'file': (uploaded_filename[0], eventlog_data[0])}
        requests.post(MIDDLEWARE_ENDPOINT+"predictivemonitor/upload-eventlog", files=files)

        #Updates the dropdown "eventlog-dropdown"
        files = requests.get(MIDDLEWARE_ENDPOINT + 'predictivemonitor/geteventloglist').json()
        options = [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in files]
        return options
    elif uploaded_contents is None:
        #Still updates the dropdown "eventlog-dropdown" even if the content is empty
        files = requests.get(MIDDLEWARE_ENDPOINT + 'predictivemonitor/geteventloglist').json()
        options = [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in files]
        return options
```

Comment: Hi MoDo, I am trying to upload and read a csv file to subsequently use it as a dataframe for my other operations, but I am not able to do it. Any way you can help?